# Updating table column date with case expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-update, case

I need to update `column8` with data depending on two other columns with dates (`date1` and `date2`) - if `date1` is later than `date2` then `column8` is `YES` otherwise its `NO`.

I wrote this:

```
update table1
set delay = case when date1 > date2 then 'YES' 
                 when date2 is NULL then 'YES' 
                 else 'NO'
            end
```

The problem is that it is probably not comparing the dates but length of the expression, because I have no in every column except for null columns... It tells me that it probably does not know I want it compare as a date But the columns in database are in date format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Is there any way to update my code or in adding something to make compare the dates and not the string lengths?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't understand. Can you edit your question and add the input data and the incorrect result you are getting?

Comment: Data type for date1 and date2 columns?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store calculated values depending on other columns. (Data redundancy, risk of data inconsistency.) Create a view instead. Or manage using triggers.)

Comment: data type for both columns is DT_DATE and as for input data and results .. input data are dates in mentioned format YYYY-MM-DD and results are comparison of those dates - new entry in column 8 depending on which date is bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try CAST function:

```
WHEN CAST(date1 AS DATE) > CAST(date2 AS DATE)
```

Comment: No taking back sorry, it helped just my mistake, thank you